# How are `MVMap` and `Page$Leaf` connected?

Tags: h2

I don't understand how a `MVMap` and a `Page$Leaf` are connected. A `MVMap` has (a `RootReference`) to a `Page$Leaf`, and the `Page$Leaf` has besides the `map` a `keys` and `values` array. You can see the `keys` and `values` from the `Page$Leaf` in the `MVMap` in a `AbstractMap$SimpleImmutableEntry<K,V>` like so,

```
arg0    Page$Leaf<K,V>  (id=818)    
    cachedCompare   0   
    diskSpaceUsed   0   
    keys    String[1]  (id=822) 
        [0] "8fa25204" (id=684) 
    map MVMap<K,V>  (id=449)    
        [0] AbstractMap$SimpleImmutableEntry<K,V>  (id=978)
                key "8fa25204" (id=684) 
                value   LongDataType  (id=414)          
    memory  -2147483648 
    pageNo  -1  
    pos 0   
    values  DataType<T>[1]  (id=849)    
        [0] LongDataType  (id=414)
```

My question is: where does this `AbstractMap$SimpleImmutableEntry<K,V>` comes from, and how do the  `keys` and `values` from the `Page` come into it?